# Natural, cheap protein food

Tags: protein, muscle-gain

Does anybody know some natural, healthy and cheap protein food for workout?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Healthy" is an outdated way to think about food. Natural could mean anything. Please consider that this depends on where you live. If you are from Denmark, Iraq or the USA matters a lot.

Comment: I am from austria. The only requirement is that it isn't produced with chemicals.

Comment: That's a meaningless statement. Water is a chemical. It's something people say to advertise their products, nothing more. It's also something where you would have to get specific down to the product. I know that there are German speaking fitness communities maybe more than there are English ones. I would ask there

Comment: For a question so broad and vague, an answer would fill books. Please explain your question more thoroughly, and spend as much time writing a good question, as you would want someone to write a good answer. Writing a question in 5 seconds and expecting a good answer is bad form. For now, just stack vegetables. I don't know how much "natural" it gets.

Comment: Additionally, you would need to expand on what you mean "protein for workout". Nutrition questions are expected to be framed in the context of supporting specific programs, not vague "I workout, what protein is best?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our area, the cheapest protein that isn't in powder form and from an animal source is cottage cheese. Eggs are cheaper until you factor in the protein in a serving of either versus the calories and cost per ounce. Dried pinto beans are perhaps the cheapest source of protein but some athletes prefer animal protein for building muscle mass. If you can handle lactose or beans either option would be a good protein source. However, because they are not pre-digested or overly processed your body will take longer to digest them and so may cause some discomfort if exercising immediately after a meal. Arguably, if you have access to hunting in your area, wild game would be hands down the cheapest source of protein. Before hunting be sure to check with your country's laws and updated information on viruses infecting local animals that may affect your health.

Answer (score 1):

I would start of with the fact that it can (most likely) only be 2 of your 3 variables at a time. If it's cheap and healthy, it might not be natural (protein powder for example). If it's healthy and natural, it's most likely not going to be the cheapest and if its both cheap and natural, it might not be the healthiest.

That being said, I'd say the most natural and healthy is going to be plant based protein. Different types of beans, nuts, seeds and vegetables for example. This might cost you a bit more though.

The most natural and cheap is probably going to be animal based protein like eggs, cheese and meat. This might not be as healthy as plant based protein if you consume loads.